# Need a formula for adding the data from sheet 1 to sheet 2

Tags: excel

I need a formula in sheet 2 to get the data from Sheet 1.

Eg:

```
Sheet 1:A
Level A
Level B
Level A

Sheet1:B
1/1/2015
1/1/2015
1/1/2015

Sheet1:C
31/1/2015
31/1/2015
31/1/2015
```

Now, I need a formula in `Sheet 2:A`, that if `Sheet1: Level A` is there then it will take `1/1/2015` and if Level B is their then `31/1/2015`.

Please let me know if any extra details you need.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
= IF(Plan1!A1="Level A"; Plan1!B1; IF(Plan1!A1="Level B";Plan1!C1;"-"))
```

Notice that if any, the value will be `-`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it sounds as though you need something like this

```
=IF(Sheet1!A1="Level A",Sheet1!B1,Sheet1!C1)
```

This will then return the above date requirement, but will take into account any changes you make to the first page.

For the below comment, please try.

```
=IF(OR(Sheet1!A1={"Level A";"Level D"}), Sheet1!B1, Sheet1!C1)
```

Comment: Thanks Chris for the formula, but now if I need to add some more options in Sheet 1:A column but the value remains the same for Column B & C. Then what would be the formula for that. Let's say I will add Level A to D and Column B & C would be same. For Level A & D would be Column B and Level B & C would be Column C.

Comment: I have added an extra line above.